# RestSharp send Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, deserialization, restsharp

I've seen how to deserialize a dictionary from the response, but how do you send one?

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "foo", "bar" },
    { "bar", 12345 },
    { "jello", new { qux = "fuum", lorem = "ipsum" } }
};

var r = new RestRequest(url, method);
r.AddBody(d); // <-- how?

var response = new RestClient(baseurl).Execute(r);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ugh...it was something else screwing up my case.  As [@Chase said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31526479/1037948), it's pretty simple:

```
var c = new RestClient(baseurl);
var r = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);  // <-- must specify a Method that has a body

// shorthand
r.AddJsonBody(dictionary);

// longhand
r.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
r.AddBody(d);

var response = c.Execute(r); // <-- confirmed*
```

Didn't need to wrap the dictionary as another object.

(*) confirmed that it sent expected JSON with an echo service like Fiddler, or RestSharp's [SimpleServer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/Helpers/SimpleServer.cs)

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it something like this, it's my example of simple post with some stuff for you, I prefer use RestSharp in this style because it's much cleaner then other variants of using it:

```
var myDict = new Dictionary<string, object> {
  { "foo", "bar" },
  { "bar", 12345 },
  { "jello", new { qux = "fuum", lorem = "ipsum" } }
};
var client = new RestClient("domain name, for example http://localhost:12345");
var request = new RestRequest("part of url, for example /Home/Index", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
request.AddBody(new { dict = myDict }); // <-- your possible answer
client.Execute(request);
```

And for this example endpoint should have `dict` parameter in declaration.