# What the best using way of Restsharp AddJsonBody? Object or body String?

Tags: c#, api, restsharp

I want to input JSONBody to method AddJsonBody in restsharp. I use this way, but i got syntax error when type VBSH:TenDV because of special character ":". So how can i fix it that i still want to do this way (I can use JSONBody String)

```
requestCreateNode.AddJsonBody(
                new { name = FileName, 
                      nodeType = "cm:content", 
                      relativePath = relativePath,
                      properties = new {
                         VBSH:TenDV = "DichVuA"//syntax error
                      }
                });
```

Comment: It looks like you're asking something similar to [this question I answered yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55608234/using-dot-notation-in-a-json-property-name-e-g-payment-token/55608299#55608299), assuming RestSharp uses JSON.NET?

Comment: so the answered is dictionary? thanks.

Comment: You can test that. I'm not sure JSON.NET is used by RestSharp (I assume it is), but if it isn't `Dictionary` might not work.

Comment: I got [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526400/restsharp-send-dictionary) from the second answer, thanks again.